# oracle insert string into number column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: `total_hhn` and `tblserviceinfo`.  They both have a column called `hhn`.  In `total_hhn` the hhn column is a number type.  In `tblserviceinfo` hhn is varchar2.  How do I insert the hhn data in `tblserviceinfo` into `total_hhn`?

```
tblserviceinfo (varchar2)
______________
1959456
2940590
6903459
3950403

total_hhn (number)
_________
```

Desired result using an insert into statement

```
total_hhn
_________
1959456
2940590
6903459
3950403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the value to a number:

```
insert into total_hhn (hhn)
    select to_number(hhn)
    from tblserviceinfo;
```